# C++ nuget package usage in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

In C# project,  I want to use a C++ .dll by using nuget package manager. Is it possible and how? An example project will be appreciated.

cppTestLIB.dll is packaged using CoApp (http://coapp.org/)

When I install this package from C# project, it gives below error.

> Could not install package 'cppTestLIB 1.0.0.0'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: What happened when you tried? Did you encounter any problems? What part of the guides that pop up when you googled "nuget C++" are you stuck with?

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic native and managed DLLs extracting from Nuget Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104838/automatic-native-and-managed-dlls-extracting-from-nuget-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by not putting non-.NET DLL to lib folder. I've not used CoApp tool.

Just by adding such a line to .nuspec file,

```
  <file src="native.dll" target="binaries\native.dll" />
```

c++ dll is packaged and it can be used from C# project.