# Automatic native and managed DLLs extracting from Nuget Package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, .net-core

This is driving me crazy for several months now and I'm still not able to achieve it. My managed libraries are extracted from the Nuget package but not the natives ones.

We have a bunch of managed and native libraries provided by another company.
We have both `x86` and `x64` version of them. In order to use them in an ASP.NET Core project I have to create an Nuget Package.

My architecture is:

- an ASP.NET Core class library that I changed to target full .NET Framework only. This project references my Nuget Package
- an ASP.NET Core website also targeting full .NET Framework and referencing the class library

Of course, at the end, I need my native libraries being extracted to the proper runtime folder of the Website (eg: `\bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64`).

For the moment my solution was:

- to put the native libs inside the `build` folder
- create a `targets` file that copies them to the `$(OutputPath)` (which is even not the runtime folder)
- add some MsBuild commands to the `xproj` of my website to get the targets file in my `$(USERPROFILE)\.nuget\packages\` folder and execute it
- copy **by hand** the native DLLs now extracted in `bin` folder to the `runtime` one

I've tried to copy them directly to the runtime folder using some configuration in `project.json` (I honestly don't remember all the things I've tried for this part) but this was always failing. Also even though I specified `SkipUnchangedFiles="true"` in my targets file, this is just ignored and my DLLs are copied to my bin folder during each build.

This is an heavy process just to achieve a DLLs extracting, now I really want to get rid of all that MsBuild and get a much simpler solution.

I know with newer versions of Nuget, it's now capable of extracting them natively without any help of adding custom MsBuild commands. As written [here](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/create-uwp-packages#adding--targets), C# projects don't even need a `targets` file

> Next, C++ and JavaScript projects that might consume your NuGet package need a .targets file to identify the necessary assembly and winmd files. (C# and Visual Basic projects do this automatically.)

I kept a tab opened in my browser for several month ([original link](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/build-for-uwp#runtimes)) and realize this resource has been recently removed from Nuget website. It was explaining how to use the `runtimes` folder to automatically extract natives DLLs. However I've never been able to get a successful result as it was explained. Now this page has been deleted and replaced by [this one](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/native-packages) with so few explanations and not talking about this `runtimes` folder at all.

My guess is that I should use `runtimes` folder for native DLLs and the `lib` one for managed but I'm not 100% sure of that. (also should I use the `build` folder?)

I've tried several things (I can't recall number of attempts, as I said several months of headache...) like [this architecture](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/create-uwp-packages#package-the-component) (I don't understand here what's the point of having `build/native` and also natives folders under `runtimes`)
[image]

I also tried to use the .NET framework version structure as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27950347/1203116) for my managed libraries.

[This](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1221#issuecomment-134379269) seems to be also part of the solution

> The architecture is ignored by the compiler when creating an assembly reference. It's a load time concept. The loader will prefer an architecture specific reference if it exists.
>
> One trick you can use to produce an AnyCPU assembly is to use corflags to remove the architecture from your x86 assembly. EG: corflags /32BITREQ- MySDK.dll. Corflags is part of the .NET SDK and can be found in VS's developer command prompt.

That's what I did, converting both x86 and x64 DLLs to `AnyCPU` (don't know if it does something for x64 DLLs but I didn't get errors) and then tried several different architectures in my Nuget package but still not working.

The default runtime without any entry in project.json is `win7-x64`, so I decided to explicitly specify it  just in case

```
"runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {}
},
```

So this is the Runtime Identifier I'm using for all my attempts in my Nuget package. However I don't care about the windows version. I would actually prefer having win-x86 or win-x64 but it seems to be an invalid value according to [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog#using-rids)

> Windows RIDs
>
> Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> - win7-x64
> - win7-x86
>
> Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012
>
> - win8-x64
> - win8-x86
> - win8-arm
>
> Windows 8.1 / Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> - win81-x64
> - win81-x86
> - win81-arm
>
> Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016
>
> - win10-x64
> - win10-x86
> - win10-arm
> - win10-arm64

However this [Github source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/v1.0.0-rc2/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json) is describing more RID so which source is right?

As you can see, there is so many mysteries here, mostly because of the lack of documentation or even contradictions between different docs.

If at least I could have a working example, then I could perform my tests to answer other questions like trying generic `win-x64` RID or see if I can include once my managed libs whatever the .NET Framework version.

Please pay attention to my special context: **I have an ASP.NET Core project targeting the full .NET Framework**

Thanks for your answers, I'm desperate to get this simple thing working.

Comment: Do you have to use NuGet Packages? I don't think you necessarily have to use them because it's ASP.NET Core project. I'm pretty sure you can Add Reference > Browse and pick a DLL?

Comment: No I can't add reference to native DLLs directly, I **have to** create a package. So I would like to pack them all (native and managed) in a single Nuget package.

Comment: Maybe look at this issue here github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/402#issuecomment-151040736 It seems that there has been ways added to load it in RC1

Comment: Especially http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/11/10/using-native-libraries-in-asp-net-5/ blog post by @Pawel, since it kind of sums it. According to David Fowl it should work in RC2 and later.

Comment: Yes I know it's possible now, I've had a quick talk about it with Jon Skeet on Twitter. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong I follow the `$/runtimes/{runtime-id}/native` structure

Comment: did you take a look at https://github.com/Mizux/dotnet-native

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I will try to explain all the pain and solutions I've been through as detailed as possible. In my example I use simple text files `AAA86.txt`, `AAA64.txt` and `AAAany.txt` instead of native DLLs to simply demonstrate the extraction process.

**First thing you need to know:**
If you try to mix the `native` NuGet's architecture with a `lib` folder containing some managed libraries, **IT WILL NOT WORK**

[image]

In that case your managed DLLs will be copied to your project's output directory but NOT your native ones.

Thanks to Jon Skeet who pointed me in the good direction, advising me to take a look at the [Grpc.Core package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core/). The trick is to create a `targets` file that will handle the DLL extraction.

[image]

Your targets file should contain something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
        <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\win-x64\native\AAA64.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <Link>AAA64.txt</Link>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' OR '$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU' ">
        <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\win-x86\native\AAA86.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <Link>AAA86.txt</Link>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Also make sure your `.targets` file is named the same as your AssemblyName. So if the name of your assembly is `DemoPackage`, your targets file should be named `DemoPackage.targets`. Otherwise, the `.targets` file might not be applied when referencing the package in another project.
[image]

Now few other things you need to know:

**1)** Visual Studio **doesn't care** at all about the settings you choose, it will always use a dummy RID. (In my case I always end up with a `win7-x64` folder even though I'm on Windows 10...)

[image]

**2)** The [platform setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#buildoptions) in your `project.json` is also totally useless

```
{
    "buildOptions": {
        "platform": "x64"
    }
}
```

**3)** In the [runtimes settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#runtimes) if you set only `win` and/or `win-x64`

```
"runtimes": {
    "win": {},
    "win-x64": {}
}
```

Visual Studio will instead use `win7-x64`. But if you add `win10-x64` while you are on a Windows 10 machine then this will be used

**4)** If you compile your application with a generic RID like this

```
dotnet build -c debug -r win
```

Then your `targets` file will receive the architecture of your machine (x64 in my case) instead of `AnyCPU` as I was expecting

**5)** With only native libraries without any managed ones, the extraction will work without a target file if you follow the architecture `runtimes/RID/native`

**6)** With only native libraries in my package, the chosen RID will always be `win-x64` building with Visual Studio as I told you the runtime folder always created is `win7-x64`, no matter the configuration I select. If I only had one single `win` RID in my package then it would successfully be picked.

#### EDIT:

As a last useful note, when working on such tasks, you might find it convenient to print out the current directory from which your `.targets` file is being executed like this

```xml
<Target Name="TestMessage" AfterTargets="Build" >
    <Message Text="***********************************************************" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="***********************************************************" Importance="high"/>
</Target>
```

Your directory will be printed out in the `Build` output in Visual Studio

Comment: If I could +10, I would, great answer.

Comment: Not sure but I think the path has to be Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\runtimes\ 
 (Only one ..\\) because currently in the your post, it tries to find runtimes in the directory where all the nuget version folders are for a particular package.

Comment: @Dimmerworld I find it odd I made such mistake considering the huge amount of time I spent on this task. Not sure if this is me or if something changed since 2016 anyway I corrected my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**As a continuation to the answer of @Jérôme MEVEL**,

**GeneratePathProperty** is a new feature which is available with `NuGet 5.0 or above and with Visual Studio 2019 16.0 or above.`

Using this feature, you can know the exact path of the installed package in the consumer of the package.
If the package is named `Mypackage.ID`, then you can refer to its path as: `$(PkgMypackage_id)` with replacing dot '.' with underscore '_'.

### In the package consumer

Add  `GeneratePathProperty="true"` attribute to the  `PackageReference`

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Some.Package" Version="1.0.0" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

### In the package creator:

Path of  the package can be reached as given below:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
        <Content Include="$(PkgMyPackage_Id)\runtimes\win-x64\native\AAA64.txt">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <Link>AAA64.txt</Link>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Notice the path is: `"$(PkgMyPackage_Id)\runtimes\win-x64\native\AAA64.txt`

For more details read: [GeneratePathProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#generatepathproperty)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of native DLLs not being copied to the output directory is gone nowadays when you use `dotnet restore` instead of `nuget.exe restore`.

The issue was solved in my case when using specifically `dotnet restore --runtime win-x64 <path_to_the_solution.sln>`.