# How to force custom NuGet package to install a c++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have some technically invalid dlls (because they are C++ dlls) that i need to have C# project's `bin` folder because other dlls depend on them. I can add the dlls manually and it works fine, but many projects need them so i created a private NuGet package.

When i try to install my nuget package I get this error:

`Failed to add reference to 'yourdll'. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.`

Is there any way to make NuGet ignore the validity of the dll and add it regardless?

MORE CLARIFICATION EDIT:

i have `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` that depends on a bunch of other dlls that are C++ dlls such as `oci.dll, ociw32.dll` and others

Comment: What's a "technically invalid dll"?

Comment: @Liam edited my question for clarification

Comment: that's not really "invalid". The C++ bit is an important detail

Comment: Looks like a [massive pain but possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40652794/542251)

Comment: @Liam thanks for the link! seems to be what i need i will look into the detailed answer