# Unresolved externals when using libpng

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, libpng, lnk2019

VS beginner here!

I'm using the [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) library, which I installed via NuGet in VS 2019, for a C++ project. I have a function `loadPng` in `renderer.h` that reads a png along the lines of the [manual](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-1.4.0-manual.pdf).
`png.h` is included. The code itself has no errors. Error message is:

`LNK2019  reference to an unresolved external symbole "png_set_sig_bytes" in function ""int __cdecl loadPng(char const *,struct img_format *)" (?loadPng@@YAHPEBDPEAUimg_format@@@Z)"`

for all the functions from the library.

How can I fix this or what did I mess up? (I suppose I didn't set up the library properly..)

Please ask, if you need to know any specific information.

The function:

```
static int loadPng(const char *filename, img_format *target) {
    FILE* fp;
    fopen_s(&fp, filename, "rb");
    if (!fp) return (ERROR);
    void* tempBuffer[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    fread(tempBuffer, 1, 8, fp);

    if (png_sig_cmp((png_const_bytep)tempBuffer, 0, 8)) return (ERROR);
.
.
.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MSVC, there are two main types of errors,

1. Errors starting with a `C` which states that its a compiler error.
2. Errors starting with a `LNK` with states that its a linking error.

Usually errors like `LNK2019` happens when the linker cannot find a library or object file. So this means that your not including the library into your linker.

To do this, go to Project `Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` and add the library file to it. And also go to `General` in the same `Linker` tab and add the path to the library file (eg: "C:\Libs") in `Additional Library Directories`. 
Optionally you can add the full file path (eg: "C:\Libs\library.lib") to the `Additional Dependencies` in the `Linker` tab.

Comment: Seems like it resolved the Error I had, thanks! Sadly NuGet somehow fails setting up the .dll file, now I have to look into that separatly.

Comment: Your welcome! Im not that familiar with Nuget but check if this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40104838/automatic-native-and-managed-dlls-extracting-from-nuget-package

Comment: Thanks again, I found another solution tho. For others: I searched for the .dll files and manually copied them to \Windows\System32 and \Windows\SysWOW64.

Comment: You should not really put files in either of these folders. Instead put the dll in the same folder as the executable.